# UIScroller inside UIWebView

Tags: uiwebview

Does any one have an idea how to access the UIScroller class  , which is the default subview of UIWebView ?

I want to handle the touches, zooming , panning and scrolling features inside the webview .

Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

I know this thread is old but if anyone comes across it there's a new way.

As of iOS 5 `UIWebView` now has a property called `scrollView` which you can't replace but you can set the properties of it. Most people just want to disable zooming/bouncing/scrolling all together which can be done by setting the properties of the scrollView for example if `webview` is a `UIWebView`:

```
webview.scrollView.bounces = NO; //Disables webview from bouncing
webview.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = webview.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.0; //Forces zoom to be at 1 (can be whatever you fancy) and disables zooming
webview.scrollView.bouncesZoom = NO; //Disables bouncing when zooming exceeds minimum or maximum zoom
```

I suppose you could set the delegate for the scrollView if you want more control, though to be on the safe side you might want to store the original delegate and call its methods appropriately in your custom delegate.

Handling the touches would be more difficult since you can't replace the scrollView to provide your own handlers. Best you could do is add some gesture recognizers as part of the `UIView` and try to handle them there, but I think `UIWebView` will still receive the events. Alternatively in iOS 5 they let you access the gesture recognizers directly on `UIScrollView`.

Answer (score 1):

You can find this by going like this:

```
[webview objectAtIndex:0]
```

That should be where it is. If not, put this in your code somewhere and run the program to search for the index of the UIScroller, and replace the 0 above with that index:-

```
for (UIView *subview in [webView subviews]){
    NSLog(@"subviews  of webView : %@", [[subview class] description]);
}
```

Comment: This assumes Apple will not change the layout or order of the subviews of UIWebView during the lifetime of your application which will normally work, and is a common 'hack'.

Comment: @Russ I agree it's not an eternally valid approach. Any suggestion of a solution then?

Comment: well a slightly better 'hack' that I've seen is this (proper code eludes me, its on my mac):
`for (UIView *v in [webView subviews]){
  if ([v class] == [UIScrollView class]){
    //Do stuff to the scroll view here
  }
}`
This will adapt if the index changes, but if they were to embed more than 1 UIScrollView (which they advise against cause gestures get confused) then you would either apply it to all of them or you could break out of the for and hope the first one is what you want. If they do change the structure by then you can use my iOS 5 answer below